# 2 torsion part of real elliptic curve.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Let $E$ be a real elliptic curve defined by $y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=f(x)$ where $f$ is a polynomial of degree 3 s.t. $E$ is non-singular with the point at infinite added.

(7.1) Assertion: An abelian, connected, compact Lie group is isomorphic to a product of $S^1$. The number of factors is equal to dimension of locally euclidean space.

There are 2 cases. $f(x)$ contains 1 real root and $f(x)$ contains $3$ real roots.

I do not understand the argument of $3$ real roots.

If $f$ has 3 real roots, then $E$ has 2 components. Then $E\cong S^1\times Z_2$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ How do I see $Z_2$ part of $E$ here? Where does $Z_2$ part entering the picture? I knew there is 2 torsion part for $E(Q)$. This had better be maintained by $E(Q)\subset E(R)$.

Ref: Elliptic Curves by Dale Husemoller Chapter on Introduction to Rational Points on Plane Curves, Sec 7.

Comment: Are you sure your equation in the first line is right? $y^2+xy+2y = x(x-1)(x+1)$ for instance is of the desired form but does not have two connected components. Anyways, if you graph instead $y^2=x(x-1)(x+1)$ you'll see the desired behavior clearly: the $Z/2$ bit is exactly the fact that there are two components, and the two torsion from $E(Q)$ are exactly the points with vertical tangent lines.

Comment: @KReiser Husemoller's argument is to transform $y^2+a_1xy+a_3y$ by completing square to canonical form $y^2=f(x)$.  Ah, I see. Thanks.